# Monitor multiple instances of same process

Tags: linux

I'm trying to monitor multiple instances of the same process. I can't for the life of me do this without running into a problem.

All the examples I have seen so far on the internet involve me writing out the PID or monitoring the process itself. The issue is that if one instance fails, it doesn't mean all the rest have failed as well.

In order for me to write out the PID for each process it would mean I'd probably have to run each process with a short delay to record the correct, seeing as the way I need to record the PID is done through the process name being probed.

If I'm wrong on this, please correct me. But so far I haven't found a way to monitor each individual process, which all have the same name.

To add to the above, the processes are run in a batch script and each one is run in its own screen (ffmpeg would otherwise not be able to run in the background).

If anyone can point me vaguely in the right direction on how to do this in Linux I would really appreciate it. I read somewhere that it would be possible to set up symlinks which would then give me fake process names and that way I can monitor the 'fake' process name.

Comment: Post what you've written so far that doesn't work to give people a hint of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

`man wait`. For example, in shell script:

```
wget "$url1" &
pid1=$!
wget "$url2" &
pid2=$!

wait $pid1 $pid2
```

will launch both `wget` processes, and wait until both processes are finished (or failed)